# hello world error on sublime text

Tags: html

I'm new to using sublime2 text editor and whenever I try to run hello world in HTML format i get the following error:

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'bash', u'-c', u"g++ 'C:\\Users\\ahadhabib\\Desktop\\My Websites!\\ch.1 html\\helloworld.html' -o 'C:\\Users\\ahadhabib\\Desktop\\My Websites!\\ch.1 html/helloworld' && 'C:\\Users\\ahadhabib\\Desktop\\My Websites!\\ch.1 html/helloworld'"]]
[dir:  C:\Users\ahadhabib\Desktop\My Websites!\ch.1 html]
[path: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\C:\Users\ahadhabib\Desktop\My Websites!\ch.1 html]
[Finished]
```

Comment: although it creates an internet file and the link actually prints hello, im not sure why im getting an error form sublime at the bottom of the editor.

Answer (score 2):

Some tips:

- Rename your folder `My Websites!` and delete the space and the exclamation mark. A good name could be: `MyWebsites`
- I think that `ch1. html` is a folder name (something like: Chapter1 html). Try to change the name of this folder for something like: `ch1_html`

> Try to don't use spaces when you name folders and files in a project. Replace them with symbols like: - or _

Answer (score 0):

`[dir:  C:\Users\ahadhabib\Desktop\My Websites!\ch.1 html]`

Please make sure to save directories (folders) and files with the [proper naming conventions](http://www.exadox.com/en/articles/file-naming-convention-ten-rules-best-practice). No spaces or special charcters.

So... you should save your file as `ch1.html` instead of what you currently have `ch.1 html`.

And the `My Websites!` directory should be renamed to something like `MyWebsites`.